# Efficient way of finding number of links between observations

Tags: loops, stata

There is a data set of the following structure:

```
firm_ID    partner_ID    start_date    end_date
1          2             01jan2001     15mar2001
1          3             15feb2001     30apr2001
2          4             20mar2001     14may2001
```

The data set shows the duration of partnership of *firm_ID* with *partner_ID*. Here, *firm_ID* and *partner_ID* (both integers) refer to a unique identifier of the firms .

Using Stata, I want to create a summary table, which shows for each unique *firm_ID* the number of its partnerships, by month and year. If the partnership existed for at least one day in a given month, it should be counted. If firm 1 reports a partnership with firm 2 but firm 2 doesn't report a partnership with firm 1, then it should only be counted for firm 1 and not firm 2.

For the example above, the summary table is:

```
firm_ID    01/2001    02/2001    03/2001    04/2001    05/2001
1          1          2          2          1          0
2          0          0          1          1          1
```

The variable *firm_ID* has 8,000 unique observations and the time span is 01/2001 - 12/2013. Thus, the resulting summary table should have the number of rows equal to 8,000 and the number of columns equal to 12*13=156 (number of months during 01/2001 - 12/2013).

Conceptually, what is the algorithm of solving this task using Stata? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with monthly dates. Note in passing that daily dates presented as you gave them need reverse engineering to be part of calculations. Type `ssc inst dataex` for a command to generate reproducible Stata data examples for public forums.

`tabulate` works for your toy example; for your real example, you will need a different tabulation to cope with many more rows and columns: see for example `groups` from SSC.

```
clear 
input firm_ID    partner_ID   str9 (s_start_date   s_end_date) 
1          2             01jan2001     15mar2001
1          3             15feb2001     30apr2001
2          4             20mar2001     14may2001   
end 

foreach v in start end { 
    gen `v'_date = daily(s_`v'_date, "DMY") 
    gen `v'_month = mofd(`v'_date) 
    format `v'_date %td 
    format `v'_month %tm 
} 

gen duration = end_month - start_month + 1 
expand duration 
bysort firm_ID partner_ID : gen month = start_month + _n - 1 
format month %tm 
tab firm_ID month 

           |                         month
   firm_ID |    2001m1     2001m2     2001m3     2001m4     2001m5 |     Total
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
         1 |         1          2          2          1          0 |         6 
         2 |         0          0          1          1          1 |         3 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         1          2          3          2          1 |         9 


groups firm_ID month, fillin show(f) sepby(firm_ID)

  +--------------------------+
  | firm_ID    month   Freq. |
  |--------------------------|
  |       1   2001m1       1 |
  |       1   2001m2       2 |
  |       1   2001m3       2 |
  |       1   2001m4       1 |
  |       1   2001m5       0 |
  |--------------------------|
  |       2   2001m1       0 |
  |       2   2001m2       0 |
  |       2   2001m3       1 |
  |       2   2001m4       1 |
  |       2   2001m5       1 |
  +--------------------------+
```